# PhpMyAdmin table gives empty column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, arduino

I am working on a project to send sensor data to phpmyadmin table using GET request.

I am not able to see sensor data in the table when I consider my Arduino to be the client, but when I use this URL on my Google chrome browser it shows the result (ex. 40).
It seems the problem is with the Arduino code.

```
int samples[NUMSAMPLES];
void loop() {
// Thermistor

 uint8_t i;
  float average;
  // take N samples in a row, with a slight delay
   for (i=0; i< NUMSAMPLES; i++) {
   samples[i] = analogRead(THERMISTORPIN);
    delay(10);
    }

  // average all the samples out
    average = 0;
    for (i=0; i< NUMSAMPLES; i++) {
    average += samples[i];
     }
    average /= NUMSAMPLES;


   // convert the value to resistance
   average = 1023 / average - 1;
   average = SERIESRESISTOR / average;

    float Steinhart;
    Steinhart = average / THERMISTORNOMINAL;     // (R/Ro)
    Steinhart = log(Steinhart);                  // ln(R/Ro)
    Steinhart /= BCOEFFICIENT;                   // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
    Steinhart += 1.0 / (TEMPERATURENOMINAL + 273.15); // + (1/To)
    Steinhart = 1.0 / Steinhart;                 // Invert
    Steinhart -= 273.15;                         // convert to C

    Serial.print("Temperature "); 
    Serial.print(Steinhart);
    Serial.println(" *C");

     delay(5000);


     Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
     // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
      Serial.println("connected to server");
      // Make a HTTP request:
       client.println("GET /add.php?");
       client.print("Steinhart=");
        client.print(Steinhart);
         }

       // if there are incoming bytes available 
        // from the server, read them and print them:
        while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        }
        }

     void setup() {
     //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
       Serial.begin(9600); 
       while (!Serial) {
       ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
       }


       // check for the presence of the shield:
       if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
        Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
          // don't continue:
           while(true);
        } 

   // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
    while (status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
     Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
      Serial.println(ssid);
        // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
        status = WiFi.begin(ssid);

      // wait 10 seconds for connection:
       delay(10000);
        } 
        Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
        printWifiStatus();


       } // end of void setup()
```

And here is my PHP code: add.php file

```
  <?php

   include("connect.php");

    $link=Connection();

     $Steinhart = ""; // or null !!
     $timeStamp="";

        $Steinhart = isset($_GET['Steinhart']) ? $_GET['Steinhart'] : '';

       date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dubai");
       $timeStamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());


      $query= "INSERT INTO `time` (`id`, `timeStamp`, `Steinhart`) VALUES (NULL, '$timeStamp','$Steinhart')";
      mysqli_query($link, $query);
      mysqli_close($link);

      ?>
```

Comment: Any help please?!!!

Comment: Be careful, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You need sanitize the variable `$Steinhart`.

Comment: How can I do so?? Can you provide me with the command that sanitize the variable Steinhart?

Comment: My table contains 3 columns (id, timestamp,  Steinhart), when I run the Arduino code the first 2 columns appear correctly in the database but the third column value doesn't appear except if I enter it directly from the web browser. For example, if I enter this URL: "http://localhost/add.php?Steinhart=40" on my browser the value of (Steinhart) appears on the table but if I try sending live sensor data from Arduino web client it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Usually send data from the Arduino board to PhpmyAdmin(Wamp Server or XXamp) with the help of NodeJS. It is pretty easy to send data with the help of NodeJS.
Here i attach the code.

```
var request = require('request');
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", {
  baudrate: 9600,
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});


serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

serialPort.on('data', sendSerialData);

function sendSerialData(data) {
 request({
  uri: "http://127.0.0.1/write_data.php?value="+data,
 method: "GET",
  timeout: 10000,
   followRedirect: true,
   maxRedirects: 10
}, function(error, response, body) {
   console.log(body);
});


}
```

By this you can easily send the data. Also you can just follow this link

http://www.instructables.com/id/PART-1-Send-Arduino-data-to-the-Web-PHP-MySQL-D3js/

Hope it will help

Comment: I have  done the steps in the link that you have posted and they are using php similar to my case.

Comment: My table contains 3 columns (id, timestamp & Steinhart), when I run the Arduino code the first 2 columns appear correct in the database but the third column value doesn't appear except if I enter it directly from the web browser.

Comment: @Rozy just check whether you are getting that value in the serial monitor of Arduino.

Comment: Yes I got it in the Arduino serial monitor